# Writing a subquery in SQL, how to combine two queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

My goal is to find the top 10 countries within the top 10 cities. I successfully used this query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(A.customer_id) AS number_of_customers,
    D.country, C.city
FROM
    customer A
INNER JOIN 
    address B ON A.address_id = B.address_id
INNER JOIN 
    city C ON B.city_id = C.city_id
INNER JOIN 
    country D ON C.country_ID = D.country_ID
WHERE 
    country IN ('India', 'China', 'United States', 'Japan', 'Mexico', 'Brazil', 'Russian Federation', 'Phillipines', 'Turkey', 'Indonesia')
GROUP BY 
    C.city, D.country
ORDER BY 
    number_of_customers DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But I would like to use a subquery rather than listing the countries which I found using a previous query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(A.customer_id) AS number_of_customers,
    D.country
FROM
    customer A
INNER JOIN 
    address B ON A.address_id = B.address_id
INNER JOIN 
    city C ON B.city_id = C.city_id
INNER JOIN 
    country D ON C.country_ID = D.country_ID
GROUP BY 
    D.country
ORDER BY 
    number_of_customers DESC
LIMIT 10
```

How can I combine these two queries correctly? I keep getting different errors when I try to replace the list of countries with in the second query I posted. I apologize if this is a stupid question; I am a beginner.

My attempt:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(A.customer_id) AS number_of_customers,
    D.country, C.city
FROM
    customer A
INNER JOIN 
    address B ON A.address_id = B.address_id
INNER JOIN 
    city C ON B.city_id = C.city_id
INNER JOIN 
    country D ON C.country_ID = D.country_ID
WHERE 
    country IN (SELECT COUNT(A.customer_id) AS number_of_customers, D.country
                FROM customer A
                INNER JOIN address B ON A.address_id = B.address_id
                INNER JOIN city C ON B.city_id = C.city_id
                INNER JOIN country D ON C.country_ID = D.country_ID
                GROUP BY D.country
                ORDER BY number_of_customers DESC
                LIMIT 10)
GROUP BY 
    C.city, D.country
ORDER BY 
    number_of_customers DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But I get an error

> subquery has too many columns

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: subquery should only return country column since it is being used in country in (....)

Comment: It is postgreSQL

Comment: I think your answer is to select solely D.country in your subquery. Then use ORDER BY COUNT(A.customer_id) DESC. Window functions could also simplify the overall logic. Can customers have varying numbers of addresses? You may want to consider using COUNT(Distinct) as this may throw the count off.
(And do please tag the db)

Answer (score 0):

For instance, in PostgreSQL you can use `with` queries, see the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```
WITH top_countries AS (
  SELECT count(A.customer_id) AS number_of_customers,
       D.country AS country
  FROM customer A
  INNER JOIN address B ON A.address_id = B.address_id
  INNER JOIN city C ON B.city_id = C.city_id
  INNER JOIN country D ON C.country_ID = D.country_ID
  GROUP BY D.country
  ORDER BY number_of_customers DESC
  LIMIT 10
)
SELECT count(A.customer_id) AS number_of_customers,
       D.country, C.city
FROM customer A
INNER JOIN address B ON A.address_id = B.address_id
INNER JOIN city C ON B.city_id = C.city_id
INNER JOIN country D ON C.country_ID = D.country_ID
WHERE country IN (SELECT tc.country FROM top_countries)
GROUP BY C.city,D.country
ORDER BY number_of_customers DESC
LIMIT 10
```